# Faraday's law and Resistors

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, electric-fields

Here is a question that was given by my instructor.
We have to find current in branches of circuit.

Now I simply calculated the line integral of driving field along the closed loop ABCA and ADBA as shown in my solution picture.

Now line integral of field along a branch of a circuit (example AC) equals 3i (i is the current in that branch). Then I used Faradays law to get the currents.

However my instructor disagrees with my answer and says that -

1. The formula £=iR (where £ is the line integral of driving field which acts on electrons in wire and R is the resistance and i is current) is not valid here. He says that we can't use this formula in presence of non conservative fields. It is only valid in case of "time invariant unilateral circuit". (I don't understand what it means), also he says that in this question the entire wire is acting like a battery and this formula is true only for "localized" battery.
2. There are 'corners' (points of non differentiability) present in the loop. So we can't even calculate line integral.

Although I agree on 2nd point but 1st point looks incorrect to me.

Also what is the power (rate of heat generation) across branch AB?

I simply answered i^2R (where i is the current in that branch). He also disagreed on this one. (I told that elections takes up energy from driving field and lose their energy due to rapid collisions that's how this formula comes from)

So please tell me what is happening in this circuit?

According to me, just when the magnetic field starts to change (at time t=0) elections in wire feels force due to induced E-field. Initially (in transient stage) the current at different  wires in circuit is not same.

Charge deposition takes place at different parts of wire until current along a particular branch (say AB) is same and Kirchhoff Current rule is followed.

Please tell me who is correct and why? Also if we assume that no corners are there and rest of the question is unchanged then will my answer be correct?

[image]

Comment: Try taking two loops ACBA and ADBA, then apply Faraday's law on both

Comment: Please view my solution I've done exactly this in my solution.

Comment: your method seems to be correct,